# Android MapBox cannot load map from OOB (APK expansion) file

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl, apk-expansion-files, mapbox-android

I have offline map from MapBox, when i load the map from `assets` folder all work fine

```
"sources": {
    "mapbox": {
        "tiles": [
            "asset://mapparis/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"
        ],
        "type": "vector"
    }
}
```

But when i load the map from mounted OBB file

```
"sources": {
    "mapbox": {
        "tiles": [
            "/mnt/obb/a2d68a13d68baf704a98a82bc8f9d62f/mapparis/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"
        ],
        "type": "vector"
    }
}
```

I have a error:

```
E/mbgl: {GLThread 7385}[Style]: Failed to load tile 0/0/0=>0 for source openmaptiles: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.HttpUrl.host()' on a null object reference
```

I parsed the mounted OBB and all folder exist like in original folder.

Answer (score 0):

Must use `file://` prefix

```
file://mnt/obb/a2d68a13d68baf704a98a82bc8f9d62f/mapparis/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf
```